# AttributeError: module 'numba' has no attribute 'targets'

Tags: pandas, numba, rolling-computation

I'm trying to utilize Numba engine when doing `rolling.apply` computation with pandas and it keeps throwing the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'numba' has no attribute 'targets'
```

I'm new to Numba and might have written the code incorrectly (see the code below). How can I improve this code?. I'm using Numba as my `dataframe` which is huge (more than 3 million rows) and would like to see if Numba can help to make my `runtime` more efficient.

```
s = re.groupby(["id","c_id"]).label.rolling("7d").apply(sum, raw=True, engine='numba')
```

Answer (score 3):

It's probably because your Numba installation is too new for your Pandas installation. (https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/5772)

- Numba <= 0.48 with Pandas <= 1.0.3
- Numba >= 0.49 with Pandas >= 1.0.4